# JS dropdown list doesn't work in a copied HTML source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have copied HTML source of this page http://webinarmeetingroom.com/webinar/?&memberid=3442&webid=289wgn4b and have uploaded it as index.html here www.interimincomemodel.info/webinar

I just added the main directory link http://webinarmeetingroom.com/webinar/ to location of some files.

I'm hosting only a copied html file and want it to sync with all the original php and js files.

The problem is that on my site when I select the date nothing happens, while on the original site it allows me to select the time afterwards.

What am I'm missing in the source code?

Thanks

Comment: Far too many unknowns for this question to be answerable as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Firebug on your page and checking the console on date change, you see the line:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://webinarmeetingroom.com/webinar/modules/regdatetime/functime2.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

That means you cannot run the scripts from a different domain.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for your answer.

But is there a way to put that file functime2.php on my domain?
And what does enabling CORS mean? Is it possible to enable it?

Comment: You can try copying all the Javascript includes (*.js files) and the embedded Javascript in that page to your test page, then change the links to your local copies.